# Spouse visa for non-Eu spouse of non-Eu Citizen on study visa in Italy

Tags: visa, immigration, residency, italy

I am a non-Eu on study visa in Italy but will change it to work visa very shortly, and recently I got married to a non-Eu. Can I apply for accompanying spouse visa (or any other if possible) with my present situation? And How many years should I stay in Italy to apply for permanent residency if I am on work permit ( for study visa it’s 5 yrs) as we do plan to settle in Italy?